# How to round off all the prices in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

Currently the price is **Rs 1,599.00** After 45% discount the price will be Rs **879.45**.

I want that the price will be round off i.e Rs 879 and then when we choose the quantity to be 18 then the subtotal price will be 15822

Check Below screens for reference.

1. https://prnt.sc/jsdn9b
2. https://prnt.sc/jsdnh1

I dont want that price will be displayed in the decimal form like subtotal,shipping,discount,tax etc etc.

I'm using Magento 2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified a method convert of file Magento\Directory\Model\Currency.

declaring a plugin, file Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> 
<type name="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency">
    <plugin name="vendor_module" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Currency" />
</type>
```

plugin model, file Vendor/Module/Model/Plugin/Currency.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;

class Currency
{
    public function aroundConvert($subject, $proceed, $price, $toCurrency = null)
    {
        $price = $proceed($price, $toCurrency);     
        // you logic
        // warning ... logic affects the price of shipping  
        return $price;
    }
}
```

Also see [Complete code](https://github.com/karliuka/m2.Price) on GitHub

Comment: Its not working

Comment: Can i upload it without using composer

Comment: not clear please can you explain more ..

Comment: Am using your module, but its not working/

Comment: See the screenshot : https://prnt.sc/jsem58, https://prnt.sc/jsem92

Comment: you added above code in your module ?

Comment: Yes, i have used your complete code from github

Comment: Its will be working in three steps: 1. Integrate your custom Module 2. Changes in the template i.e vendor\magento\module-tax\Model\Calculation.php 3. vendor\magento\module-quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Grand.php

Answer (score 0):

We need to override Magento\Catalog\Model\Product file like below :

> **Create** /Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml and copy below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
    <plugin name="change_product" type=" Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
</config>
```

> **Create file** /Vendor/Module/Plugin/Product.php and copy below code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;


    class Product
    {
        public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
        {
            return round($result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create file and use this code :

=> From :

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

=> To :

> app/design/frontend/VendorName/ModuleName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

this file is defined from `\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount`

The price itself is coming from this call:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
```

If we take a look at the file that this method is created based on the class it's inheriting (`/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render/Amount.php`)

Update line no 24

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
```

To

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer() , 0) ?>
```

You need to override

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js

To

> app/design/frontend/VendorName/ModuelName/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-utils.js

and change the value of precision on line 38:

```
var precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision,
```

To

```
var precision = 0,
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me.

Comment: can you tell me where issue generated ?

Comment: I already check that and it's working for me. There are something going wrong. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

please use this plugin. This is Best solution  and tested in 2.3 and working fine.

https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal

Gopal