# Magento 2: How to implement decimal quantity with round off

Tags: magento2, quantity

How to use quantity in decimal, I know Magento has this feature by default.
But I want to make this decimal quantity to round off feature.
for example 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 if any user put 0.15 it should convert it to 0.2

Comment: Similar - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229119/how-to-round-off-all-the-prices-in-magento-2

Comment: This is for the price, I am asking for quantity.

Comment: You need to share the code and files you are trying or using or where you have to apply this in screenshots etc.

Comment: I am using decimal quantity by Catalog > Product > Advanced Inventory from magento admin panel. I am not using any code still trying to get the idea, which plugin type should I use to round off quantity.